# Making single endpoint for different API using laravel

Tags: database, laravel, api

I had a project that need me to make a single endpoint for different payload format using Laravel. Since i'm pretty new to Laravel and i still learning it for a few days, i want to know how to approach this and how is the method to saving the different payload into same database? Thanks for the reply.

since you guys asking the case, this is the case

first payload:

```
case_1 = { 
    "date_of_test":"20210227134300", 
    "id_number":"IC000A2", 
    "patient_name":"Patient A4", 
    "gender":"F", 
    "date_of_birth":"19940231", 
    "lab_number":"QT196-21-124", 
    "clinic_code":"QT196", 
    "lab_studies":[
        {
        "code":"2085-9", 
        "name":"HDL Cholesterol", 
        "value":"cancel", 
        "unit":"mg/dL", 
        "ref_range":"> 59", 
        "finding":"A", 
        "result_state":"F"
        } 
    ],
 }
```

second payload:

```
case_2 = { 
    "patient_data":
    {
        "id_number":"IC000A3", 
        "first_name":"Patient", 
        "last_name":"A5", 
        "phone_mobile":"+6500000000" 
        "gender":"M", 
        "date_of_birth":"19940231",
    }, 
    "date_of_test":"20210227134300", 
    "lab_number":"QT196-21-124", 
    "clinic_code":"QT196", 
    "lab_studies":[
    {
        "code":"2085-9", 
        "name":"HDL Cholesterol", 
        "value":"cancel", 
        "unit":"mg/dL", 
        "ref_range":"> 59", 
        "finding":"A", 
        "result_state":"F"
    } 
  ],
 }
```

Comment: Hi, why do you want to do that? Could you give us mor information? Please explain your use-case!

Comment: you can have different http methods on same endpoint "/user" POST, PUT,DELETE with different payload , are u looking for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand your question properly but if you ask about different http request methods with same endpoints so you can do like this

```
Route::get('/same-end-point', 'XYZController@show');
Route::post('/same-end-point', 'XYZController@store');
Route::put('/same-end-point', 'XYZController@update');
Route::delete('/same-end-point', 'XYZController@destroy');
```

Or if you ask about to save different payloads in same database so you can make a column in your table with type JSON and save your payload into that column
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiIQJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not sure how different your cases are that you want to store.
If there are a reasonable amount of case-types, then I would recommend, to create multiple endpoints for that.

Otherwise you can still define your API, to accept a attribute e.g. `case_info` that accepts a json format of unstructured data. Then you can insert this data in a either noSQL database such as MongoDB, or you serialize it, and put it in a SQL database.
(although the latter one is NOT RECOMMENDED. You'll be having a hard time in a few years or even less, working with that).

If you choose to go that way, you just need to make sure, that your client (that presents the data to the enduser is able to handle this different stored formats.